# Where is the kibana error log? Is there a kibana error log?

Tags: kibana-4

QUESTION: how do I debug kibana?  Is there an error log?

- PROBLEM 1: kibana 4 won't stay up
- PROBLEM 2: I don't know where/if kibana 4 is logging errors

DETAILS:
Here's me starting kibana, making a request to the port, getting nothing, and checking the service again.  The service doesn't stay up, but I'm not sure why.

```
vagrant@default-ubuntu-1204:/opt/kibana/current/config$ sudo service kibana start
kibana start/running, process 11774

vagrant@default-ubuntu-1204:/opt/kibana/current/config$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:5601'
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host

vagrant@default-ubuntu-1204:/opt/kibana/current/config$ sudo service kibana status
kibana stop/waiting
```

Here's the nginx log, reporting when I curl -XGET from port 80, which is forwarding to port 5601:

```
2015/06/15 17:32:17 [error] 9082#0: *11 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: kibana, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5601/", host: "localhost"
```

UPDATE: I may have overthought this a bit.  I'm still interested in ways to view the kibana log, however!  Any suggestions are appreciated!

I've noticed that when I run kibana from the command-line, I see errors that are more descriptive than a "Connection refused":

```
vagrant@default-ubuntu-1204:/opt/kibana/current$ bin/kibana
{"@timestamp":"2015-06-15T22:04:43.344Z","level":"error","message":"Service Unavailable","node_env":"production","error":{"message":"Service Unavailable","name":"Error","stack":"Error: Service Unavailable\n  at respond (/usr/local/kibana-4.0.2/src/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:235:15)\n  at checkRespForFailure (/usr/local/kibana-4.0.2/src/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:203:7)\n  at HttpConnector.<anonymous> (/usr/local/kibana-4.0.2/src/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/connectors/http.js:156:7)\n  at IncomingMessage.bound (/usr/local/kibana-4.0.2/src/node_modules/elasticsearch/node_modules/lodash-node/modern/internals/baseBind.js:56:17)\n  at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)\n  at _stream_readable.js:944:16\n  at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)\n"}}
{"@timestamp":"2015-06-15T22:04:43.346Z","level":"fatal","message":"Service Unavailable","node_env":"production","error":{"message":"Service Unavailable","name":"Error","stack":"Error: Service Unavailable\n  at respond (/usr/local/kibana-4.0.2/src/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:235:15)\n  at checkRespForFailure (/usr/local/kibana-4.0.2/src/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:203:7)\n  at HttpConnector.<anonymous> (/usr/local/kibana-4.0.2/src/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/connectors/http.js:156:7)\n  at IncomingMessage.bound (/usr/local/kibana-4.0.2/src/node_modules/elasticsearch/node_modules/lodash-node/modern/internals/baseBind.js:56:17)\n  at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)\n  at _stream_readable.js:944:16\n  at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)\n"}}
vagrant@default-ubuntu-1204:/opt/kibana/current$
```

Comment: The error, specifically, is probably the same as: 
- https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/2813
- https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/2822

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Kibana 4 logs to `stdout` by default. Here is an excerpt of the [`config/kibana.yml`](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/master/config/kibana.yml) defaults:

```
# Enables you specify a file where Kibana stores log output.
# logging.dest: stdout
```

So when invoking it with `service`, use the log capture method of that service. For example, on a Linux distribution using Systemd / systemctl (e.g. RHEL 7+):

`journalctl -u kibana.service`

One way may be to modify init scripts to use the `--log-file` option (if it still exists), but I think the proper solution is to properly configure your instance YAML file. For example, add this to your `config/kibana.yml`:

```
logging.dest: /var/log/kibana.log
```

Note that the Kibana process must be able to write to the file you specify, or the process will die without information (it can be quite confusing).

As for the `--log-file` option, I think this is reserved for CLI operations, rather than automation.

Comment: chown kibana:kibana /var/log/kibana.log This worked for me

Answer (score 5):

In kibana 4.0.2 there is no --log-file option. If I start kibana as a service with `systemctl start kibana` I find log in  `/var/log/messages`

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you need to pass a flag "-l, --log-file"

https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/3407

```
Usage: kibana [options]

Kibana is an open source (Apache Licensed), browser based analytics and search dashboard for Elasticsearch.

Options:

    -h, --help                 output usage information
    -V, --version              output the version number
    -e, --elasticsearch <uri>  Elasticsearch instance
    -c, --config <path>        Path to the config file
    -p, --port <port>          The port to bind to
    -q, --quiet                Turns off logging
    -H, --host <host>          The host to bind to
    -l, --log-file <path>      The file to log to
    --plugins <path>           Path to scan for plugins
```

If you use the init script to run as a service, maybe you will need to customize it.

Answer (score 3):

Kibana doesn't have a log file by default. but you can set it up using log_file Kibana server property - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/kibana-server-properties.html

Comment: note, that since version 4.2 `log_file` property is deprecated. `logging.dest` must be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

For kibana 6.x on Windows, edit the shortcut to "kibana -l " folder must exist.